# How to find region of convergence (if you do follow me) of the series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^n\tan\left(\frac{x}{3^n}\right)$$
Please, I need Your help

Comment: Is $x$ a constant?

Comment: It's just Cauchy-Hadamard theorem.

Comment: no, it is functional series)

Comment: What methodologies do you know?

Comment: Is there a missing exponent on $x$?  That is, should it read $x^n$?

Comment: Could You explain that Cauchy-Hadamard theorem cuz I am beginner, and do not pretty much understand functional series

Comment: Nope, there are no missing exponent, everything is right

Comment: @user449259 See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Hadamard_theorem

Comment: @user449259 if you want to reply to a particular user, you should write "@" followed by their name, as I have done. This will give them a notification, otherwise they may not see your reply.

Comment: @JohnDoe ok, I got it

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Note that eventually, $|x|<3^n$ and, by the inequality $|\tan(t)|\le 2|t|$ which holds for $|t|<1$, we have 
$$2^n\left|\tan\frac{x}{3^n}\right|\leq 2|x|\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n.$$
What may we conclude?

Answer (score 1):

Using *equivalents*, we see$\; 2^n\biggl\lvert\tan\dfrac x{3^n}\biggr\rvert\sim_\infty\Bigl(\dfrac23\Bigr)^n\lvert x\rvert $. The latter is convergent whatever $x$, hene the given series is absolutely convergent for all $x$.

Comment: This is the approach I would recommend to a student.

Answer (score 0):

using the fact that
$$\tan (X)\sim X \;\;(X\to 0)$$
we conclude that

$$\tan (x/3^n)\sim x/3^n\;\;(n\to+\infty) $$

thus the general term of your series is equivalent to

$$x\left(\frac {2}{3}\right)^n$$

which is always convergent.